# When passing parent component function to memo children components, it avoids rerendering only if its parent is class component and arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-memo

I am new to React, and in my app, I have to optimize it to avoid unnecessary rerendering. So far, I have found that there is `shouldComponentUpdate` for `React.Component` and `React.PureComponent`, and `memo` for functional components. I am using memo as I want to use functional components. However, I found that it does not always avoid rerendering in certain scenarios. I have created an example in this sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-tristan-kfrwmh?file=/test-rendering.tsx

In the example, I have two types of components: `ParentClassComponent` and `ParentFunctionalComponent`. Both of them have two buttons that use memo. One button uses an arrow function to update the count, while the other uses a regular function. Clicking those buttons will show log messages in console to indicate if rerendering is triggered.

Through my experiment, I have concluded that `memo` only works as expected for class components and arrow functions. I am not sure why this is the case. My assumption is that the arrow function is bound to the instance of the class component, so when `ParentClassComponent` needs to rerender, it just calls the `render()` function. As a result, when passing the function to children, it still refers to the same function. On the other hand, `ParentFunctionalComponent` gets called during rerendering, so functions are created again regardless of whether they are arrow functions or functions inside the component.

I would like to know how to pass a function (or arrow function) in `ParentFunctionalComponent` so that the memoized children can avoid unnecessary rerendering. Is this possible?

Comment: Your example is not working

Comment: @Arst, I believe you're looking for https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback

Comment: @OktayYuzcan Thanks for the reminder. This is m first time to use sandbox. I forgot to save! Just redid it again. Fixed.